# AWS EB .ebextensions skipping - Contains invalid key

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been trying to deploy my php code but i get this error

```
    Error processing file (Skipping): '.ebextensions/setup.confi`g' - Contains invalid key: 
'chmod -R 777 /var/dubcut/uploads/uploads'. For information about valid keys, see 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html`
```

and this is my ebextension file

## ebextensions config file

```
packages: 
#ebextensions config file

packages: 
  yum:
    incron: [] 
    sox: []

container_commands:
#Create an upload directory and make it world-writable:
mkdir -p /var/dubcut/uploads
chmod -R 777 /var/dubcut/uploads/uploads
mkdir -p /var/dubcut/transcoded

#Copy the incrond script to /etc/incron.d and make it executable:
cp transcoder/dubcut.incrond /etc/incron.d
chmod -R 755 /etc/incron.d/dubcut.incrond

#Copy the transcoding script to /var/dubcut and make it executable:
cp transcoder/do_transcode.bash /var/dubcut
chmod -R 755 /var/dubcut/do_transcode.bash

#Copy the ffmpeg binary to /usr/local/bin and make it executable
cp ffmpeg /usr/local/bin
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

tried multiple commands: but still same error

Answer (score 0):

Your container commands are not in the correct format.  See the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands) for the syntax.  You need to set them up like this:

```
container_commands:
  00_create_upload_dir_1:
    command: mkdir -p /var/dubcut/uploads
  01_create_upload_dir_2:
    command: chmod -R 777 /var/dubcut/uploads/uploads
  02_create_upload_dir_3:
    command: mkdir -p /var/dubcut/transcoded
  03_copy_incrond_script_1:
    command: cp transcoder/dubcut.incrond /etc/incron.d
  04_copy_incrond_script_2:
    command: chmod -R 755 /etc/incron.d/dubcut.incrond
```

etc. Note that the container commands run in alphabetical order by name, so you need to make sure that you appropriately name the commands.